# Adding data in the database using microsoft access

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I really can't add any data in my database, I can read what's on the DB but can't write, I've tried many codes but didn't work :( I ended up with this code,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string user = textBox1.Text;
                string pass = textBox2.Text;

                string myExecutequery = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username,Password) VALUES (@user,@pass)";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(myExecutequery, con);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

the error says that:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at VirginiTEAcorp.Form3.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\12-014s\My Documents\applications\Database\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form3.cs:line 31
```

someone help me pls :(

Comment: you need to add the parameters by using either cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues(??,parameter values) or 
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@user, user)`
`cmd.Parametes.AddWithValue(@pass, pass)`

Comment: Try this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/csharpgeneral/thread/52293d38-931d-40a6-8999-ca74d5a0fb8f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string myExecutequery = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username,Password) VALUES 
(@user,@pass)";

con.Open();

try
{
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(myExecutequery, con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", user);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", pass);     
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cmd.Dispose();
 cmd = null;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
}
finally
{
 con.Close();
}
```

**OR**

Your query should be like this

```
string myExecutequery = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username,Password) VALUES 
('"+ user +"','"+ pass +"')";
```

And you need to open the connection before it is adding to **oleDBCommand** like

```
con.Open();
```

Comment: There is a much better way of doing the Insert.. I would recommend using Parameterized query in your case however since its `CRAPCESS` that would work.. if it were Sql Server, what you have would be a bad solution because of how the OP has his query setup to TextBox entries it sets himself for Sql Injection

Comment: What if the value is in the textbox? how can I do that, If I use VALUE("'" + textBox1.text +"'", textBox1.text)

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try.

```
       string SqlString = "Insert Into Accountstbl (Username, Password) Values (@user, @pass)";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\test.accdb")) //Your Connection string
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
            {
                string use = userTextBox.Text;
                string pass = passTextBox.Text;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@use", use);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I know this should be work but I tested this code in `Microsoft Access 2012` and I got this Error:

```
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

This is would be a bug of `MSAccess` [BUG: "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO..." on ADO Recordset.Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189220)

Comment: Spajce, why are you hard coding values pass the proper Params in your example this  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@use", "test");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", "test1"); should be `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@use", user);`
                `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);`

Comment: my apologize i will modify my answer.. `:)`